# How to make Swing use my own HTMLEditorKit for JLabel/JButton/etc

Tags: java, html, swing, htmleditorkit

Lets say I've made a sublcass of `HTMLEditorKit` (and other relevant classes) in order to display some custom HTML tags.  I want to be able to to use these custom tags in `JLabel`, `JButton`, and so on.  Is there any way to do this beside creating my own look-and-feel?  That is, I want to tell swing "use this instance of `HTMLEditorKit` for rendering HTML in `JLabel`/etc" regardless of what look-and-feel is currently being used.  From the little poking around I've done in Swing internals I don't think it's possible, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Swing JComponents accepted HTML <= 3.2 syntax, then I cann't see any problem with that, but JComponents are for ONE LINE usage by default, except JTextArea, JTextPane

Comment: I don't think it can be done either. You can check out the `BasicHTML` class to see how the `BasicEditorKit` is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done:

The key is in the class `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI`, which is a basic UI for labels.

In the paint method, we can see this code:

```
View v = (View) c.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey);
if (v != null) {
    v.paint(g, paintTextR);
}
```

A BasicHTML class is the supplier of HTML capabilities in Java, so, theoretically, if you replace the client property for `BasicHTML.propertyKey` with your own implementation of View, then that class will be used and you can do whatever you want to render the text.

The class `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI` is the parent of most of other LAF label UIs out there, but not all, so it may not work for all LAFs. LAFs that don't support HTML using the `BasicHTML` class will not work with your fix, either.

But IMHO this is more of a hack than feature. You are programming againts implementation, not interface. So if you don't have really serious reasons to do that, I would suggest to find a cleaner way to render your custom HTML, such as JLabel subclass.

Comment: aaaaach, could be interesting +1

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done normally . . . If you extend the `JLabel` and `JButton` classes, it might be possible, but these seems like a lot of work for something there are better ways to do[1].  Would be useful classes though.

[1]:  If the text doesn't need to be dynamic, try using images in `JImagesIcons`.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6540252
The bug reporter proposes a several workarounds.

Comment: Please include the essential part of the link contents in the answer. If the link breaks your answer will be useless